How to debug a CMake + Cuda project on Windows with Visual Studio
I have a project at work that is being developed for Windows and Linux that is written with Cuda and because of the cross-platform nature of the project it uses CMake to manage builds.
Building and debugging on Linux is pretty straight forward. Download VSCode, the CMake and NSight extensions and then it's basically the exact same as a C++ project. You run conan install for the dependencies, use CMake to configure the project with the conan preset and then use VSCode's launch system to debug the project. Everything works like syntax highlighting, symbol resolution, etc.
On Windows however, it seems impossible to setup in a working fashion. I have tried both creating a Visual Studio solution via CMake and then opening that. In that case it didn't recognise any of the Cuda provided functions or symbol resolution.
I also tried opening the CMake file directly, in that case it couldn't even find the files provided by Conan to generate the project and when I finally copied the right files around to get it to work, while it would build, it was still unable to resolve any symbols or debug the Cuda kernels themselves.
I created a demo version of the project that replicates the setup of the project at work to demonstrate the usage here. Has anyone got a good setup for getting CMake Cuda projects on Windows working with Visual Studio.

If the question is not self-contained, then this might be better submitted as a ticket to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues.

While I agree there is some kind of issue related to conan, I don't think it's conan itself that is the issue. Since CMake running VSCode could find the same files just fine

Have you tried to use the Conan configuration tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:toolset_cuda, pointing to the folder where the toolkit is installed? It will update the CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET with cuda information.

I can try, but again, just to be clear; I managed to get Visual studio to find the conan files by moving them around and generate a project file including the ability to locate the Cuda compiler. But it still didn't have any understanding of the project, no symbol resolution, or the ability to debug the kernels
